# Esper deployment on jboss as 7.X, event type or class name not found

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss7.x, esper

I have developed a java ee project to be deployed on jboss as 7 server.
scenario is

```
A java ee project in which ejb module contains execution classes.
some of the pojo events are defined in another plain java project lets say p1
  and p1 is referenced in java ejb module and it appears in ./lib directory 
  of ear where other jar files exists.
auto-import tag in esper-config.xml has been added for p1 classes.

"cepConfig.cnfigure(esper-config.xml)" executes fine and 
   I can see all event types as reuired in debug mode.
"EpServiceProvider.getProvider("MyEngine",cepConfig)" results in error
   which says "could not find event type or class named p1.mypack.class1"
```

I have checked reference and deployment settings of projects. **p1.jar** exists in ./lib directory.
All classes are public and accessible. what other things i need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class "p1.mypack.class1" would need to be part of the classpath, either the Jboss system classpath or the module classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I Think putting my project p1 as module to jboss will solve the problem. This is solvable from jboss end. So marking this as answer.